# Why is 4-hydroxyacetophenone more acidic than 3-hydroxyacetophenone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

At 25 °C, the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of 3-hydroxyacetophenone is 9.19, while the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of 4-hydroxyacetophenone at the same temperature is 8.05. Why is that so?

[image: 3-hydroxyacetophenone]
3-hydroxyacetophenone

[image: 4-hydroxyacetophenone]
4-hydroxyacetophenone

Comment: Have you heard of mesomeric effect?

Comment: Please note that names of chemicals should not be capitalised, unless at the beginning of a sentence. Additionally, there is no space between substituents ('hydroxy') and the parent compound ('acetophenone').